# Get unique set of adjacent vertices in python bulbs or gremlin?

Tags: python, gremlin, bulbs

Using `python`, `bulbs`, and `rexster`

Say I have two vertices, `v0` and `v1`. And I create 3 outgoing edges from `v0 -to-> v1`. Currently in `bulbs`, `list(v0.outV())` gives me a 3 element list, all of `v1`.  Is there a way to get the unique list of `v0.outV()` in `bulbs` or `gremlin`?

Note: `set(list(v0.outV()))` doesn't work, and I prefer not to remove duplicates in `python`, but rather on the graph server, `rexster` side

Edit: I'm using `rexster` with `orientDB`, and `orientDB` is `blueprint` compatible.

Comment: You need to specify the graph database rexster is using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are issuing Gremlin I would guess `dedup` is the right step for you:

```
v0.outV().dedup
```

You can read more about it here:

http://gremlindocs.com/#filter/dedup

Answer (score 1):

Use Gremlin...

```
>>> from bulbs.rexster import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
>>> script = "g.v(vid).outV().dedup"
>>> params = dict(vid=1234)
>>> vertices = g.gremlin.query(script, params)
>>> vertices.next()    # or list(vertices) to convert the iterator to a list
```

See the Bulbs Gremlin docs...

- http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/gremlin/
- http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/rexster/gremlin/